# copy elision doesn't require present and accessible of copy or move ctor since c++17

Tags: c++, c++17

Before C++17, the below code snippet appears to cause the compiler to complain, but it will work since C++17.

I am looking at [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), in which I don't see any updates on it for C++17. But, instead, I only see that prvaule operand will return compiler to omit copy and move.

Can anyone point me to the C++ standards on this change?

`atomic<int> atoc_1 = 1;`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point of your question. It works because that's what guaranteed copy elision says happens; it's nothing specific to `atomic`. Also, that page starts with a *gigantic* block of C++17-only text; how did you not "see any updates on it for C++17"?

Comment: @NicolBolas what I mean is that I do see there are some updates for C++17 that copy elision will be guaranteed in some cases but I suppose the paragraph below to say that copy/move ctor is required should be pre-c++17 only.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the committee paper (P0135r1)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0135r1.html) that provided the precise diff between C++14 and C++17 to make this change.  It's a fair amount of wording and is not easy reading.